# How i can show resultant value in input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

//Here i want to convert the temperature from celcius to farenheit using javascript.When i enter the value of celcius it calculates currectly and i can show the result using alert.But i want to show the result in Farenheit input field.how can i?

```js
//var celcius = document.getElementById("celcius")
//var farenheit = document.getElementById("farenheit")
function converter() {
  farenheit.value = (celcius.value * 1.8) + 32;

  alert(farenheit.value);
  document.getElementById("farenheit") = farenheit.value;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.celcius {
  text-align: center;
}

.farenheit {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <h1>Temperature Converter</h1>
    <div class="celcius">
      <label>Celcius:</label>
      <input type="number" id="celcius" placeholder="Enter Temperature In Celcius">
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="btn1">
      <button onclick="converter()">Converter</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="farenheit">
      <label>Farenheit:</label>
      <input type="number" id="farenheit" disabled>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: i want to show my calculation value in the second text field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this.

```
function converter() {
  farenheit.value = (celcius.value * 1.8) + 32;

  alert(farenheit.value);
  $("#farenheit").val(farenheit.value);
}
```

Comment: Sure, just use jquery even if its not tagged nor written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `farenheit.value` directly.

```js
function converter(event) {

var celcius = document.getElementById("celcius")
var farenheit = document.getElementById("farenheit")
farenheit.value = (celcius.value * 1.8) + 32;

}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.celcius {
  text-align: center;
}

.farenheit {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <h1>Temperature Converter</h1>
    <div class="celcius">
      <label>Celcius:</label>
      <input type="number" id="celcius" placeholder="Enter Temperature In Celcius">
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="btn1">
      <button type="button" onclick="converter()">Converter</button>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="farenheit">
      <label>Farenheit:</label>
      <input type="number" id="farenheit" disabled>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: `var celcius = document.getElementById("celcius");
var farenheit = document.getElementById("farenheit");` can be omitted.

Comment: Yes but It depends upon weather It has usage outside the function or not, If not then they should be define inside the function.

Comment: Thanks it works.Problem was i used form tag.Therefore it could not catch the value.

Answer (score 0):

according to what said [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) you can use `document.getElementById("farenheit").value`

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML on button set `type="button"` and JS code should be

```
function converter() {

   var farenheit = (document.getElementById("celsius") * 1.8) + 32;

    document.getElementById("farenheit").value = farenheit;

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your javascript to this:

```
//var celcius = document.getElementById("celcius")
//var farenheit = document.getElementById("farenheit")
function converter() {
  farenheit.value = (celcius.value * 1.8) + 32;

  alert(farenheit.value);
  document.getElementById("farenheit").value = farenheit.value;
}
```

Comment: You either use `farenheit.value = (celcius.value * 1.8) + 32;` **or** `document.getElementById("farenheit").value = (celcius.value * 1.8) + 32;`. Both is redundant.

Comment: @Ohidul I am glad that it worked for you. Thanks, for posting challenges for us and keep posting.